# How to configure mozilla Firefox build options to build a customized release/developer edition build?

Tags: firefox, build, mozilla

I'm trying to build a release version Firefox. But after the build there seems still a little bit different compare to the official build. Such as the official build doesn't contain the folder chrome/, components/, gmp-fake/ etc in the root of Firefox folder.

Current build options:

```
mk_add_options AUTOCLOBBER=1

ac_add_options --enable-application=browser
ac_add_options --enable-artifact-builds
ac_add_options --target=x86_64-pc-mingw32
ac_add_options --host=x86_64-pc-mingw32
ac_add_options --disable-tests
ac_add_options --enable-optimize
ac_add_options --enable-release
ac_add_options --disable-crashreporter
```

My question is how to configure the options to build a version just like the official Firefox but it's a nightly build? 
Where can I find the build options, such as release/developer edition, which are used by mozilla?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Finally get help from the mozilla dev in google group. A most simplest way is navigate to "about:buildconfig" in browser to get the current build options. Post answer in here in case anyone anyone meet the same issue.

Comment: For future reference, here's the link to the [dev-platform thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.dev.platform/Ifiu3Q003Kk).